# PHP - Display different sentence on every page load

Tags: random, pageload, sentence

What I need is, I want to save an array of different sentences and let one of them randomly display on every pageload. Would that be possible? If yes, then how?

Comment: Put all the sentences in an array, select one at random and display it. What's the problem?

Comment: I don't know PHP yet.

Comment: Then use Python, Perl, Ruby, or whatever language you know.

Comment: It's very easy to find a [solution](http://www.3till7.net/2005/06/08/random-quotes-with-php/) on the web using Google. Please invest some research effort before asking trivial questions here.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array("red","green","blue","yellow","brown");
$random = array_rand($a);
echo $a[$random] ;
```

Comment: `array_rand()` returns the key, not the value. You need `echo $a[$random]`.

Comment: I'm with Barmar on that